# need advice on how to get this to work

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I need to get the content to be visible when the link on the side bar is clicked as its too long. I have the following links and have sections separated with div tags. and a JavaScript function that I call from the anchor tags, but its not working it doesn't change the content. Can you please tell me how to do this. Much appreciated

## Anchor Tags

```
<a href="" id="mySelect" onclick="return myFunction();" value="about">
   <h4>Who we Are</h4>
</a>    
<a href="" id="mySelect" onclick="return myFunction();" value="mission">
   <h4>Our Mission & Vission</h4>
</a>    
<a href="" id="mySelect" onclick="return myFunction();" value="director">
   <h4>Director & Advisory Board</h4>
</a>
```

## Section Tags

```
<div id="about" style="display: block;">default content</div>
<div id="mission" style="display: none;">content</div>
<div id="director" style="display: none;">content</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        if (x=="") {
          document.getElementById("about").style.display="block";
          document.getElementById("mission").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("director").style.display="none";
        } 
        if (x=="about") {
          document.getElementById("about").style.display="block";
          document.getElementById("mission").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("director").style.display="none";
        } 
        if (x=="mission") {
          document.getElementById("about").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("mission").style.display="block";
          document.getElementById("director").style.display="none";
        }
        if (x=="director") {
          document.getElementById("about").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("mission").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("director").style.display="block";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Elements can't share the same id.

Comment: Echoing @Marty, specifically ' id="mySelect" x3'...

Comment: if i remove the myselect id from the anchor tags you think it will work ?

Comment: No, I think you also need to get the value properly from the clicked anchor.

Comment: No, there is a whole assortment of things wrong at the moment. The next thing to look at would be your trying to compare an element returned from `getElementById` with a string.

Comment: how to call the value of the anchor tag then?? without a id???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzrey0eL/2/) and the code below.

## HTML

```
<div id="about" style="display: block;">default content</div>
<div id="mission" style="display: none;">content</div>
<div id="director" style="display: none;">content</div>
<a class="mySelect" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="about">
  <h4>Who we Are</h4>
</a>
<a class="mySelect" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="mission">
  <h4>Our Mission & Vission</h4>
</a>
<a class="mySelect" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="director">
  <h4>Director & Advisory Board</h4>
</a>
```

## JS

```
function myFunction(vm) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySelect");
  var id = vm.id;
  if (id == "") {
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("mission").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("director").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (id == "about") {
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("mission").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("director").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (id == "mission") {
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("mission").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("director").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (id == "director") {
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("mission").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("director").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Edit:

Here's the two JSFiddles

[SubMenu](https://jsfiddle.net/wzrey0eL/2/)

[Directed to Page](https://jsfiddle.net/sto2xyae/1/)

JSFiddle behavior will make them act a little strange, JSFiddle will open the link in the iframe. The code in JSFiddle is all mock due to JSFiddle blocking you from getting the JSFiddle URL. On a normal site you can un-comment the code and remove the other fake code.

Comment: hey thanks alot.... it works but the section comes and it goes back to default content within seconds any idea why that happens??

Comment: Try now, I accidentally didn't do the the latest version. Re-run the link.

Comment: hey need another help.. do you know how i can call this function from another page... eg. if i use the same sections as submenus to direct to this page and for that particular section to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely should not have duplicate IDs, it is semantically incorrect and you should not do it.

You should restructure your code, the best approach is using classes.

bellow have aa code where will help you to understand better, is just one way to identify your click, of course have others ways.

take a look where I'm passing `this` for the function

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>
    <a href="" class="mySelect" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="about">
       <h4>Who we Are</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="mySelect" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="mission">
       <h4>Our Mission & Vission</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="mySelect" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="director">
       <h4>Director & Advisory Board</h4>
    </a>
   </body>
   <script >
       function myFunction(x) {
           if (x.getAttribute('value')=="about") {
            alert(x.getAttribute('value'));
           }
           if (x.getAttribute('value')=="mission") {
            alert(x.getAttribute('value'));
           }
           if (x.getAttribute('value')=="director") {
            alert(x.getAttribute('value'));
           }
       }
    </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: when you identify the correct click you can do what you want

Comment: what is the problem? in my code I identify the click, now you need take the correct action each click, did you understand?

Comment: hey yeah i did... but it didnt change..... then i used the other code.... but i debugged this too later.. when the href attribute is there it doesnt open...